# Dealing With GLIBC Versions

Tags: c++, linux, unix, glibc, libc

So recently I updated my tools so I could build an application I work on without depending on the Steam Runtime so I could use a new GCC\G++ version to use C++17.

However running the application on another Linux distro results in my application failing to load properly due to a newer GLIBC. It seems the Steam Runtimes uses 2.15 whereas my distro has 2.27.

How can I work around this? Is there an easy way for me to link to the older version?

I just don't particularly know how this works.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Linux standard base but that doesn't even support c++11 yet never mind 17. Newer language features require a newer standard library, probably the only fully working solution is to link to and ship your own glibc.

Comment: Ouch. Alright, I guess I'll have to build glibc. I assume I just download it, build it, and link against it in my application? That sounds a bit too simple.

Comment: @MichaelBarth Well you obviously haven't tried to build glibc before... You then also need to rebuild and link any libraries you use (including libstdc++) to link against your glibc. Linux really isn't designed for cross distribution binary applications

Comment: The other option is to use a lowest common denominator distribution like centos and then install the dev toolset https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/ i don't know how portable the resulting binaries are though